# How to determine a channel is a DM or a normal channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I got a bot which may:

- start talk when user say somethibng in DM with the bot.
- start talk only when user mentioned the bot in some channel.

Question:

How can I know it's a DM channel or a normal channel?

I guess https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.info might help, but I'm not sure which property indicates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approach is to use the [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) API method. It will tell you exactly what kind of channel it is. It actually replaces the older `channels.info` method (which only works for public channels anyways).

Among other you get:

```
"is_channel": true
"is_group": false
"is_im": false
```

Here is how those terms are used in the API and (mostly) in the documentation:

- channel = public channel
- group = private channel
- im = direct message.
- conversation = any kind of channel

Alternatively you can also guess the channel type based on the first letter of it's ID. That is not 100% though, because channels can be converted from one type to another while keeping their ID.

- C: public channel
- G: private chanel / MPIM
- D: Direct Message / IM

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!